# Login failed for user

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, connection-string

I downloaded SQL server 2012 and created a local database called 'Test'.
I then tried to access it through my c# code in VS like this:

```
    class sqlTOdataTable
{
    DataTable IndexWordsTable;
    SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter;
    private string connectionString = @"Server=localhost\SQLExpress;Database=Test"; 

    public sqlTOdataTable(string TableName)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter command");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Console.ReadLine(),connection);
            SqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        }
    }

}
```

whenever it gets to "connection.Open();" the 'Login failed for user' error appears.
Is the something wrong with the connection string?

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to access with your logged in account, try adding:

```
Trusted_Connection=True;
```

If not you need to specify your user name and password created in SSMS:

```
User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
Trusted_Connection=True;
```

so you connectionstring will be

```
private string connectionString = @"Server=localhost\SQLExpress;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;";
```

See [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012#sqlconnection)

This assumes that you have installed SqlServer Express to use as [Authentication Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143705%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) the Windows Mode. In this way your SqlExpress accepts your windows user credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True";
```

Answer (score 0):

You must provide SQL Server Login/Password in the connection string if in your server instance Mixed-Mode authentication allowed. If only `Windows Mode` allowed you must login using Windows credentials.